# Methods for aquiring non-Japanese books/movies that have been translated/dubbed (in my own country)

Tags: discussion

Aside from ordering items from Amazon.jp, or other Japan-based websites, are there good (and less expensive) ways to get some TV shows or movies or books that are originally in one language (in this case, English), but have been dubbed or translated into Japanese?

I'd like to watch some of my favorite TV shows in Japanese for practice, and also to add a little something else to them (a couple shows I love I've watched and re-watched quite a few times...).

I don't know how to go about finding it, but I wonder if there's a Japanese version of Netflix (that is available in the US), or a DVD-Kinokuniya.

If worst comes to worst I can just save up and get them through Amazon, but if anyone has any suggestions, I'd welcome them!

Comment: Just for reference, I'm really looking for Disney movies, Stargate SG-1, and Frasier for videos, and the Harry Potter books for...books :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you are, but you might be amazed what turns up second-hand on Ebay. If you want to just look at what what's generically available, try "Japanese edition"/"Japanese release" - more films than TV series.

Harry Potter in Japanese often turns up on Ebay, I think usually being resold where someone has imported it in for practice and then found the level was too high for them. That's how I got my copy, anyway.

I think you'd need extremely good luck to find something like Frasier but you could probably find some Disney.

(Postage cost from Amazon is the painful bit - you might want to shop around if you do decide to import stuff).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is not too obvious but:

Have you investigated what is available to the Japanese community in Canada(?)?

Most cities around the world there is fairly good infrastructure that serves them quite well. These days I should expect there is good supply of cable/internet TV for the Japanese expat market.

Dropping into places like the embassy or Japanese/Asian supermarkets may also yield results.

Answer (score 0):

I use hulu.jp in Japan, which they support japanese subtitles.

Comment: Do you mean "in Japan"? ^.^

Comment: @silvermaple, yes, thanks for correction.